# Docker image build Error : unable to find user admin: no matching entries in passwd file

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile

here's how my Dockerfile look like :

```sh
[root@centos7 ~]# cat Dockerfile
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
#use centos image
FROM centos

# Add none root user
CMD  useradd admin && echo "admin:admin" 
CMD  chpasswd
CMD  adduser admin sudo
USER admin

#install python git and gcc libs

RUN sudo yum install python3 python3-devel git gcc sassc redhat-rpm-config libxslt-devel  \
    bzip2-devel openldap-devel libjpeg-devel freetype-devel
```

When I lunch the build of the image here's the error I encounter :

```yaml
Step 6/24 : RUN sudo yum install python3 python3-devel git gcc sassc redhat-rpm-config libxslt-devel      bzip2-devel openldap-devel libjpeg-devel freetype-devel
 ---> Running in 4d6c76160178
unable to find user admin: no matching entries in passwd file
```

anyone has an idea/suggestion why the user entry in the passwd file is not found ?

Comment: The bigger thing here is that you're already running as root, so you don't need `sudo`; just delete it and `RUN yum install ...`.  You don't need to add a second root-equivalent user with an easily-guessed password recorded in plain text.  The flip side of this is that an image only has one `CMD`, and it only runs when the container starts (after the build completes), so `useradd admin` never happens at all and `adduser admin sudo` would only happen when you `docker run` the image.

Comment: @david maze Thank you for the comment I changed my Dockerfile content but I am still facing the issue on the step of the libraries and software installation

Comment: Also delete the `USER admin` line.  (Here there's no reason to switch to a non-root user but then run a privileged command via `sudo`; just be `USER root` the whole time.)

Comment: staying root goes against best practice while building an image espcially if this image is destined to be for a tool like Odoo because the installation of postgresql and odoo should be done by a sudoer user that is exactly the issue here even in odoo's installation guide it is forbidden to install using root that's why i am trying to have a sudoer other that root

Comment: How is creating a user with a known password, installing sudo, and giving the user sudo access to run a command as root more secure than running the command as root? I consider this a bug in the oodo install. You're trying to apply VM security practices to a container where they don't apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing CMD with RUN as shown below will solve your issue.

```
  #Add none root user
  RUN  useradd -m admin && echo "admin:admin" |  chpasswd &&  usermod -aG wheel  admin
```

next step for you is to add sudo command in container as it is not present by default.